# Adobe Acrobat FindText thats not there vba

Tags: vba, acrobat

So I've been trying to make a vba macro that parses through multiple PDF files using Adobe Acrobat. It takes pages that contain a specific word and makes those into a new PDF file.

I've been running into an error where if the PDF file does not have the specific word, it holds up the entire macro indefinitely.

my code is:

```
If AVDoc.FindText("do", 0, 0, 0) Then
    Set PageArr = PDFDoc.GetAVPageView
    PageArr.GetPage
    PageNum = PageArr.GetPageNum
End If
```

How would I avert the hangup?

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/302355

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help my situation. I want to use vba instead of vbs

Comment: VBA and vbscript are more or less the same language, at least as far as this situation goes.  The link was really just to point out that the return value from `FindText` seems to be unreliable, and also to note that a failed FindText seems to trigger a messagebox from Acrobat, so maybe that's what's locking up your code.

Comment: Well this is for work and unfortunately I cannot access WshShell on these devices. Thank you for the help.